# What kind of capacitor should I use in Buck topology if the load is a lead-acid battery?

Tags: capacitor, battery-charging, buck, component-selection, lead-acid

[image]

I'm using [BQ2031](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/bq2031.pdf) to charge lead-acid batteries. BQ2031 takes battery voltage as feed back and controls the switching element according to it. Now the load is not a passive element, instead it is a battery with a very low internal impedance. The battery itself will behave as a huge capacitance. In this case, what kind of capacitor should I use, or should I use one?

Specifications
Maximum charge current: 30A
Maximum ripple current: 2A peak-to-peak
Battery type: Generic, not a specific one

Comment: I'd use something that would match the ESR of the battery.

Comment: Your cct is NOT a valid buck converter. D1 should be from gnd (cathode) to L and switch junction.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon I have it fixed now.  
I also placed D2, because I used high and low side MOSFET pair as the switching element. Since the load is an active element, the circuit would drain the battery slowly from the high side MOSFET when the main power supply is off.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, I'd use this guide to the [BQ2031](http://www.ti.com/general/docs/lit/getliterature.tsp?literatureNumber=slua017&fileType=pdf) - it has a fuller description and includes a circuit diagram. I'm saying this because the diagram in the question is probably not going to work.

As for the output capacitor, \$C_O\$, this should be a decent low ESR type and placed close to where the inductor and \$R_S\$ is on the circuit board: -

[image]

I've circled the diode that is needed (and missing from the diagram in the question). Also circled is \$R_S\$ which is in the milli-ohm range and is required when the battery leads are very short.

It should also be noted that the diode (preventing battery discharge when the charger is not powered) should not be used where the question diagram proposes. See DB1 on diagram above.

Comment: The charger would die fast if the battery was connected the wrong way .Is there any possibility of this ocuring?

Comment: @Autistic who are you addressing?

Comment: Andy and anybody contemplating building the charger.